# If $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty$ and $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=+\infty$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

There is the following exercise in a book:

> $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) \leq \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n + \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n $

And the author(Kazuo Matsuzaka) writes as follows in his solution without proofs:

> If $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty$ and $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = +\infty$, then $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = +\infty$.
>
> If $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty$ and $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = +\infty$.

Please tell me how to prove the above two statements if they are true.

Please tell me counter examples if the above two statements are false.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You just have to prove that, for all $n\in\mathbf N$, one has:
$$\sup_{k\ge n}(a_k+b_k)\le\sup_{k\ge n}a_k+\sup_{k\ge n}b_k $$
then use the basic results on (ordinary) limits.

Answer (score 1):

In this general form, the statements in the solution are incorrect. For the first part, let $a_n = (-1)^n n$ and $b_n = -a_n$. For the second part, let $a_n = \begin{cases}0&n \text{ odd} \\ n, & n \text{ even} \end{cases}$ and $b_n = -a_n$.

Note that in order to prove the original statement $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) \le \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n + \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n$, these cases are irrelevant. As soon as the right-hand side is $+\infty$, the inequality is automatically correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your counter examples, Mr. Dominik.

Answer (score -1):

The first is easy to prove:

Since,for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n \leq \sup_{k\geq m} a_k 
$$
If:
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n = +\infty
$$
Then:
$$
\sup_{k\geq m} a_k = +\infty
$$
Therefore if:
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n = +\infty\\
\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n = +\infty
$$
Then, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$
\sup_{k\geq m}a_n = +\infty\\
\sup_{k\geq my}b_n = +\infty
$$
Therefore:
$$
\sup_{k\geq m}a_n > 0\\
\sup_{k\geq m}b_n > 0
$$
Therefore:
$$
\sup_{k\geq m}a_n + \sup_{k\geq m}b_n > \sup_{k\geq m}a_n
$$
By the linearity of $\sup$:
$$
\sup_{k\geq m}(a_n + b_n) > \sup_{k\geq m}a_n
$$
Taking limits on $k$(allowable since the inequality is valid for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$):
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{k\geq m}(a_n + b_n) > \lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{k\geq m}a_n
$$
Thus, by the definition of $\limsup$:
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n + b_n)  > \limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n
$$
Since:
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n = +\infty
$$
Therefore:
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n + b_n) = +\infty
$$

I'll have to think about the second statement.

Comment: This is highly incorrect, the Supremum is not linear! See also my answer for counter-examples.

Comment: It isn't? Dangit, always thought it was, but then again I don't know much about supremum's and infinums. Could you possibly point me towards a article on them?

Comment: Well, this other question states that it is slightly linear: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810890/supremum-property-of-functions

Comment: You have to carefully check what the statements in the other question state. Note that in the equality there are two different variables $x, y$ over which the suprema are taken.